# KDB+/Q Mark if next price change is positive or negative

Tags: kdb

I have a table like below (without the *goesUp* or *isUp* columns), and I want to make a boolean column with the end result of *goesUp*; a column that signals if the next price movement is positive or not. I tried the below, but it's only accurate when the next tick changes. So, for row 2, AAPL's next price change is from 2 to 3, so it should be true. However, I've written it so that it's only looking at the next price and it sees 2=2, so considers it false.

How can I change my table update so that it looks at the next price change instead of the next price?

```
test:([] time:09:30:00.500000000 09:30:00.500500000 09:30:00.600000000 09:30:00.610000000 09:30:00.610100000 09:30:00.620500000 09:30:00.621000000 09:30:00.630000000 09:30:01 09:30:02 09:30:03; RIC:`AAPL`AAPL`AAPL`IBM`AAPL`AAPL`AAPL`IBM`IBM`IBM`IBM; price:1 2 2 11 3 2 1 12 12 11 12; goesUp:`Y`Y`Y`Y`N`N`NA`N`N`Y`NA);
result:update isUp:(0b;1b) price< next price by RIC from test;
```

| time | RIC | price | goesUp | isUp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0D09:30:00.500000000 | AAPL | 1 | Y | 1 |
| 0D09:30:00.500500000 | AAPL | 2 | Y | 0 |
| 0D09:30:00.600000000 | AAPL | 2 | Y | 1 |
| 0D09:30:00.610000000 | IBM | 11 | Y | 1 |
| 0D09:30:00.610100000 | AAPL | 3 | N | 0 |
| 0D09:30:00.620500000 | AAPL | 2 | N | 0 |
| 0D09:30:00.621000000 | AAPL | 1 | NA | 0 |
| 0D09:30:00.630000000 | IBM | 12 | N | 0 |
| 0D09:30:01.000000000 | IBM | 12 | N | 0 |
| 0D09:30:02.000000000 | IBM | 11 | Y | 1 |
| 0D09:30:03.000000000 | IBM | 12 | NA | 0 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be of help. Use `differ` to find only those points where the price changes then `reverse` and `fill` the list to get the next price, reversing again to retain the correct order. From there a comparison can be made between the current and next prices.

```
q)update isUp:(next reverse fills reverse ?[differ price;price;0N])>price by RIC from test
time                 RIC  price goesUp isUp
-------------------------------------------
0D09:30:00.500000000 AAPL 1     Y      1
0D09:30:00.500500000 AAPL 2     Y      1
0D09:30:00.600000000 AAPL 2     Y      1
0D09:30:00.610000000 IBM  11    Y      1
0D09:30:00.610100000 AAPL 3     N      0
0D09:30:00.620500000 AAPL 2     N      0
0D09:30:00.621000000 AAPL 1     NA     0
0D09:30:00.630000000 IBM  12    N      0
0D09:30:01.000000000 IBM  12    N      0
0D09:30:02.000000000 IBM  11    Y      1
0D09:30:03.000000000 IBM  12    NA     0
```

I was also able to take a similar approach using `fby` to find the next change in price, but this was less performant on your sample. The outcome may be different in a real world scenario.

```
q)update isUp:fills[nextPrice]>price by RIC from update nextPrice:next price by RIC from test where (differ;price) fby RIC
time                 RIC  price goesUp nextPrice isUp
-----------------------------------------------------
0D09:30:00.500000000 AAPL 1     Y      2         1
0D09:30:00.500500000 AAPL 2     Y      3         1
0D09:30:00.600000000 AAPL 2     Y                1
0D09:30:00.610000000 IBM  11    Y      12        1
0D09:30:00.610100000 AAPL 3     N      2         0
0D09:30:00.620500000 AAPL 2     N      1         0
0D09:30:00.621000000 AAPL 1     NA               0
0D09:30:00.630000000 IBM  12    N      11        0
0D09:30:01.000000000 IBM  12    N                0
0D09:30:02.000000000 IBM  11    Y      12        1
0D09:30:03.000000000 IBM  12    NA               0
```